# Why doesn't this regex work Even though it is valid and runs fine on test code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation, file-upload

I already put several posts out here on SO, related to this but yet this is another one that works on test code and not with regular expression validator control with **clientScript Enabled** i want the fileUpload to be validated on the clientside at time of upload.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="rgvFile" runat="server" font-bold="true" errormessage="Only pdf, txt, doc, docx, png, gif, jpeg, jpg, zip, rar files allowed"
cssclass="rgvfile" enableclientscript="true" display="Dynamic" controltovalidate="fileUpload"
validationexpression="(.pdf|.txt|.doc|.docx|.png|.gif|.jpeg|.jpg|.zip|.rar)$"
text="Only pdf, txt, doc, docx, png, gif, jpeg, jpg, zip, rar files allowed" tooltip="Only certain files allowed. Filename must be within 30 letters and cannot contains invalid characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

validation expression does is check for valid file extensions[forget about extension forgery ,where changing file extension and uploading is done.]. I tested above on regExHero, regexBudy all validate file. I also tested it like below.

```
"domreference.pdf".match(/(.pdf|.txt|.doc|.docx|.png|.gif|.jpeg|.jpg|.zip|.rar)$/);
```

which produces `[.pdf,.pdf]` which is correct. But when used inside a Regular Expression validator it doesn't even validate correct file names.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but you only match the extension - shouldn't you match the whole file name?

Comment: @Frank ahhhmm Stupid huh, Did you know that FileUpload behaves totally different in each browser. Firefox returns only `filename.ext` chrome return `c:\fakepath\fileName.ext` ie returns `FullPath.ext` so how do you even validate such a thing. btw FileNames are validated on server

Comment: differences aside, they all return the complete file name. Frank didn't ask that stupid a question.

Comment: @kooinlnc you got any suggestions then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the script written by Microsoft wasn't cross browser and they never though of it.

```
function RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val) {
    var value = ValidatorGetValue(val.controltovalidate);
    if (ValidatorTrim(value).length == 0)
        return true;
    var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression);
    var matches = rx.exec(value);
    return (matches != null && value == matches[0]);
}
```

where `val = value of FileUpload' which is different for each browser. Hence even if valid match was found the last return statement would return false because value would never be equal to the match in this situation

Answer (score 3):

First, note that you didn't escape the dots:

```
\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$
```

Comment: I'd also try adding `.*` at the start, but I can't find reference it is needed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.validationexpression.aspx

Comment: did you know even know that regexValidator control escapes the backslash there when it put's the validation expression in page. You expression will be transformed to `\\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)` btw what's the point, including `.` inside your regex saves few key strokes :)

Comment: @Deeptechtons - I don't quite follow... Anyway, I just realized you're talking about a file upload control - aren't they sometimes blocked from JavaScript?

Comment: sorry i could not be clearer enough. Yes i am validating a fileUpload control using regexValidator that comes with Asp.net Controls. The above regex fails on all valid file names. Hence this question any more confusions